# how can I query all wordpress users of a blog

Tags: plugins, themes, users

How can I loop through all Wordpress users in a blog, and sort them in ascending order by their usernames?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [**`get_users()`** Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users).

```
$users = get_users();
```

You can pass the function an array of arguments, including:

```
$args = array(
    // Order by username (display name)
    // Note: 'login' is default
    'orderby' => 'display_name',
    // Order (note: 'ASC' is default)
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$users = get_users( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Would the [get_users](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) function from WordPress work for your needs?